# How can I solve the "Window.onDomReady is not a function" problem?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/mytemplate/javascript/min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                                var mooTrans= Fx.Transitions.<?php echo $this->params->get('transition','Sine.easeOut') ?>;
                                window.addEvent('domready',function(){
                                new SmoothScroll({ duration: 500, transition: Fx.Transitions.linear}, window);
                                });
                                </script>
```

and this is the code in the min.js file:

```
Window.onDomReady(function() {new DropdownMenu($E('#hornav ul.menu'))});
```

However, I am getting this error: Window.onDomReady is not a function.

Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong?
Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are using MooTools framework and in your code there is addEvent call for domready event:

```
window.addEvent('domready',function(){
    new SmoothScroll({ duration: 500, transition: Fx.Transitions.linear}, window);
});
```

In your min.js file you can use the same approach:

```
window.addEvent('domready',function(){
    new DropdownMenu($E('#hornav ul.menu'))}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is no `Window` but only a `window`. Then there is no `onDomReady` attribute. There might be `ondomready` though. However, it's better to use actual even binding.

jQuery and other JavaScript frameworks make this pretty easy by providing helper methods for it, e.g. `$(document).ready(...);`

Answer (score 1):

You are using MooTools. The proper method for listening to a DOMREADY event is the the following:

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() {new DropdownMenu($E('#hornav ul.menu'))});
```

Answer (score 0):

After an Upgrade from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5, I faced this issue. When I used Firefox's Tools > Developer > Web Console to check the error, it was caused by incorrect JS code of Joomla 1.5. When i went to edit the code, I saw the Joomla 2.5 JS code. I viewed the source of the validate.js file in the browser and refreshed the page to get the non cached file from the server. This worked for me. So this was a caching issue.